# Cloud Print queue forwarding via Wi-Fi

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

This question is about registering Google Cloud Print printers with a Google account and automatically forwarding queued jobs from an Android device to a non-cloud Wi-Fi printer. Let me explain:

I'm using a PHP script that sends print jobs to any printer registered with my Google account.
https://github.com/yasirsiddiqui/php-google-cloud-print

Now, I'm thinking of the following scenario.

- I have a Wi-Fi thermal printer that is not cloud-ready
- in order to register it with my Google account, I need to connect this printer to a laptop
- after registering the printer, I remove the laptop
- my PHP app sends print jobs to this printer via the mentioned API
- my Android phone, connected to the same WiFi network as the printer, constantly checks queued jobs and forwards any new jobs to the printer.

Will there be any problems with this scenario?

Can an Android phone forward queued jobs directly to the printer via WiFi?

The docs (https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=en) say if a printer is not cloud-ready, it needs to be first registered with a Google account using a laptop, but once this is done, can the laptop be removed?